# "I voted" moderator election profile flair

Tags: feature-request, election, flair

After voting for moderator elections there should be some "*I voted*" style flair to add to our profile to raise awareness of the election.

[image: atwood]

Some diamonds, unicorns, waffles - whatever gets the word out.

Comment: Everyone that checks their inbox already gets a notification to vote, right?

Comment: Not the point, maybe it's just an USA thing...

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Well, if you step into your voting booth at a national election, everybody can see you doing so. They just can't see who you voted for, but they can see that you support democracy. And we already have the badge that's connected to voting, which is visible to all. So, I guess, this feature would just add a bit of extra visibility, and it might notch people to take a second look at the current election.

Comment: Hrmm, now that I think of it the [Constituent](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent) badge already discloses that information.

Comment: [You've earned the "Constituent" badge for an election. See your profile.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/188613)

Comment: @mike, yup, that one. Guess I was worrying for nothing after all.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi Unlike the [Constituent](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1974/constituent) badge, this would be optional.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar - But no one notice the latest badge you have earned. Only if they go to our profile see the badges section. By seeing this type of flair may be someone visit the election.